# iPhone - How to hide app icons or restrict from opening

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was wondering whether or not it is possible on iOS to use a switch (UISwitch) to hide an application icon from the iPhone home screen? 
Or stop that app from opening at all?

Comment: This question is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may not be able to hide the apps, you can [enable restrictions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213).

Comment: Restrictions don't include Phone, Messages, Mail. They are forever calling, SMS or mailing people by accident. Now when I turn on air plane mode they are prompted if they want to turn it back on when they click safari etc. I was to be able to stop calling, any real internet or data access without being prompted to turn it off.

Comment: Two other options: 1) don't give your phone to your kids 2) use Guided Access and allow only a single app